# How to Calculate the distance passed by a car for a day, and for entire month

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application, distance

So I  have three classes such as :

```
internal class Checkpoint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Coordinates { get; set; }
}

internal class Log
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public int CheckpointId { get; set; }

}

internal class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Coordinate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

And I want to calculate the distcane the Car travels per day according to the registration points. If the user is registered at point A only, I get the coordinates of his home and calculate the distance between his home, the checking point A and back to his home.
If he is registered in Point A and B , I take the coordinates from Home to A to B and then Back to Home.

So my program is as follows :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        var listOfUsers = new List<User>(); //get users from db
        var listOfCheckpoints = new List<Checkpoint>(); //get checkpoints from db
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var user in listOfUsers)
        {
            string address = user.Coordinate;

            DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(2014, 8, 1);
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();

            while (currentDate <= DateTime.Now)
            {
                double dayUserDistance = 0.00;
                var listOfUserLogs = new List<Log>(); //Get logs where day == currentDate from db
                var previousCoordinate = address;
                foreach (var log in listOfUserLogs)
                {

                    Checkpoint checkpoint = listOfCheckpoints.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == log.CheckpointId);


                    dayUserDistance += DistanceCalculator.GetDistance(previousCoordinate, checkpoint.Coordinates);
                    previousCoordinate = checkpoint.Coordinates;

                }
                dayUserDistance += DistanceCalculator.GetDistance(previousCoordinate, address);

                dictionary.Add(currentDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), dayUserDistance);

                currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
            }

            sb.Append(user.Name + " ; ");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> keyValuePair in dictionary)
            {
                sb.Append(keyValuePair.Value + ";");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

But when I run it I don't get anything printed in the Console. The console is blank.

Can you please let me know what I am missing. I have connected the database to the console app, since I have all the data needed in the database.

Comment: Is there any hidden code? at this point: //get users from db?? else you hav to add the actual code to do this

Comment: Maybe you should be writing something to the console then. How about `Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());`

Comment: You're not seeing anything because you're not writing something to the console. `Console.WriteLine()` just prints a newline. MAybe you wanted to make `Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())`

Comment: It seems that a lot of code is missing or has never been written. List of users, list of  checkpoints, list of logs, the  DistanceCalculator.GetDistance. Please if you ask why my code is not working you should provide all the code relative to your issue

Comment: Well this is all my code. And I add the Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()) I get nothing still. 

@Steve What do you mean? I am not so good at this can you explain me a little bit what should I add more??

Comment: @AhmedHMehiny you have declared the three lists, but do you really load them from the database? If so, how do you do that? The call to DistanceCalculator.GetDistance is supposed to calc something but how do we know if it works or not? Also you need to use the debugger and follow step by step this code to find out why you don't have any value returned.

Comment: @DrKoch I connected the app to the database through the connection string ? So I am assuming when I create the list of users it is taken automatically from the database ...or not ?

Comment: @Steve How is the loading is done ?

I am still a beginner :/

Comment: Sorry but to answer I need to write a book. Now your question is really to broad. I think you need a good tutorial on ADO.NET

Comment: Oh I see. So I need to laod the data first from the Database. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From writing a line like

```
 var listOfUsers = new List<User>(); //get users from db
```

you just have an empty list. No data is read from the database.
You have to add some code which reads records from the database and populates your listOfUsers.

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing anything on the screen. Your code is reaching the Console.WriteLine and writing a blank line, and then on ReadLine it's waiting for text input.

```
Console.WriteLine(//what you want printed here);
```